# insert jquery value to php variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#t_select").change(function(){
                var table_name = $("#t_select").val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'index.php',
                    data: {"tabname": table_name},
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log('Data send');
                             $("#display-property-address").html(data);
                    }
                });
    });
    });
    </script>
```

This my jquery code

```
<form name="stable" method="POST" id="form"> 
                        <select id="t_select">
                        <option value="agent_info">Agent info</option>
                        <option value="student_info">Student info</option>
                        </select>
                    </form>
```

my html code

```
 <?php

    if($_REQUEST['table_name'])
    {
    $val=$_REQUEST["table_name"];
    echo $val;
     }else{echo "nothing";}
  ?>
```

i want to get the option value from the select box using jquery on change event and i want to insert that value into PHP.

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: echo $table_name=$_POST['table_name']; in ajax page.Did you try this?

Comment: IN ajax page:

echo $_POST['tabname'];

Below of jquery

<div id="display-property-address"></div>

Comment: It working fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/ny50h1nd/ what is your problem?

Comment: Sorry i didn't mention the php code,i want to assign the jquery value to php variable.

Comment: What is your code in `index.php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help friends,here is my solution

```
    index.php

    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $(".t_select").change(function()
                {
                //alert($('#t_select').val());
                    //var tabname = $('#t_select').val());
                    var table_name = $(this).val();
                //  alert(table_name);
                    $.ajax
                    ({
                        type:"POST",
                        url: "data.php",
                        data: {tabname :table_name},
                        //cache: false,
                        success: function(html) {
                            console.log('Data send');
                               $("#display-property-address").html(html);
                        }
                    });
        });
    });
        </script>

    <select class="t_select" name="t_select">
                        <option value="agent_info">Agent info</option>
                        <option value="student_info">Student info</option>
                        </select>


<div id="display-property-address"></div>

data.php

<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php include 'db.php';?>   
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>    

        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Subject</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Unit</th>
                        <th>Semester</th>


                    </tr>   
                  </thead>

             <?php
             //print_r('tabname');
             echo $_POST['tabname'];
    if($_POST['tabname'])
    {
    $val=$_POST['tabname'];
    echo $val;
     }else{echo "nothing";}
    ?>
        <?php   
                $table_name = $_REQUEST['tabname'];
                $SQLSELECT = "SELECT * FROM $table_name ";
                $result_set =  mysql_query($SQLSELECT, $conn);
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_set))
                {
                ?>

                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row['SUBJ_ID']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['SUBJ_CODE']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['SUBJ_DESCRIPTION']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['UNIT']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['SEMESTER']; ?></td>


                    </tr>
                <?php
                }
            ?>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable you are sending from JS is called tabname.

This should fix it.

```
  if($_REQUEST['tabname'])
    {
    $val=$_REQUEST["tabname"];
    echo $val;
     }else{echo "nothing";}
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about your problem? Does the request reach your php page? Are you receiving a response, but not the right response?

Answer (score 0):

In ajax you have to use like

```
data: {"table_name": table_name},
```

instead of

```
data: {"tabname": table_name},
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `$("#t_select option:selected").val()`;